# Using weblogc 12.2.1.4 with jdk1.8.0_251 getting deployment error saying CDI definition failure:WELD-001325

Tags: deployment, weblogic

Using weblogc 12.2.1.4 with jdk1.8.0_251 getting deployment error always saying CDI definition failure:WELD-001325 No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment

When deploying any war/ear always getting below error text in console.

An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error

```
CDI definition failure:WELD-001325: No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException:WELD-001325: No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment

Error from log:
<BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "43151356394900" for task "5" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:WELD-001325: No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:WELD-001325: No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001325: No instance of an extension class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider registered with the deployment
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getExtension(BeanManagerImpl.java:1497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getExtension(ForwardingBeanManager.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.processAnnotatedType(ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processAnnotatedTypes(BeanDeployer.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createTypes(BeanDeployment.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:384)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.initialize(WeldInjectionContainer.java:94)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:80)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Same issue faced with wls 12.2.1.3 also.

Comment: Can you provide more details to understand how this issue can be replicated?